# How to create array for text file searched by user input?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment in which the program needs to read a file located by user input.
The file is scanned and an array is created.
The array stores in words as strings and outputs how many times a word has been used.
Then, the output is printed out into a new file.

```
package TestFileReader;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Prompts user for file by asking for its location
    Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName;

    System.out.print("Enter file location, or 'Quit' to quit: ");
    fileName = keys.nextLine();

    Scanner textFile = null;

    //try catch block for exception
    try
    {
        textFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException s)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found, confirm location: ");
    }

    //File will be read continuously until there is no next line
    while(textFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        String contents = textFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(contents);
    }

    textFile.close();



    //New Class for saving read into array
}
}
```

Comment: Are there any limitations on your assignment? I mean can you use all the classes in the JDK? For example, can you use class `java.nio.file.Files`?

Comment: After reading a line, you can split the line by the characters you define, e.g. empty string or comma or whatever. Then each word and the corresponding count could be stored in a `Map<String, Integer>`.  After reading, you write each record of this map into a file.

Answer (score 0):

While I prepared the following example, Jan also answered properly that a `HashMap` can be used for this job:

```
        HashMap<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        //File will be read continuously until there is no next line
        while(textFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = textFile.nextLine();

            // Split line into words
            String words[]=line.split("\\s+");
            for (String word : words)
            {
                // Get current word count
                Integer count=map.get(word);
                if (count==null)
                {
                    // Create a new counter for a new word
                    map.put(word,1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Increase existing word counter
                    map.put(word,count+1);
                }
            }
        }

        // Output result
        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+": "+entry.getValue());
        }

        textFile.close();
```

The HashMap gets filled with an Integer counter for each word. If the word is found again, the counter will be increased. HashMaps are usually faster than nested loops over an array when you expect more than 20 entries.

Example inout file:

```
This is a test
This is another test
Wuff!
```

Example output:

```
a: 1
Wuff!: 1
test: 2
another: 1
This: 2
is: 2
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I have been trying to do this assignment for the past week. Thank you :'). How does one learn about Java? My professor does not teach.

Comment: Learning by doing. And of course talking to other developers. In the company we discuss our problems and solutions to coach each other.

Comment: Nice sample, @Stefan.  One modification that you might want to get into the habit of:  Never declare Collections to be any more specific than they need to be.  So your declaration of map should be

    Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();

The fact that you are implementing it today with a HashMap is a detail that should only exist as part of the creation of the object.  Tomorrow you might change it to be a TreeMap, so you don't want any downstream code depending on it being a HashMap.

Comment: That's a matter of taste. Such examples are easier to read if I do not use more different class types than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 you could also use the Streams API to accomplish this task.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Prompts user for file by asking for its location
        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName;

        System.out.print("Enter file location, or 'Quit' to quit: ");
        fileName = keys.nextLine();

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            stream.flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("\\W")))
                    .filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum))
                    .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot read file: " + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```